# Unit Test with Async is Inconclusive with FluentAssertions and NSubstitute

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nsubstitute, fluent-assertions

I'm testing this factory

```
    public class ContratoFactory : IContratoFactory
    {
        private readonly IContratoPodeSerCriadoValidation _contratoPodeSerCriadoValidation;

        public ContratoFactory(IContratoPodeSerCriadoValidation contratoPodeSerCriadoValidation)
        {
            _contratoPodeSerCriadoValidation = contratoPodeSerCriadoValidation;
        }

        public async Task<IValidationResult> Build(Contrato entity)
        {
            try
            {
                var result = _contratoPodeSerCriadoValidation.Valid(entity);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                // throw 
            }
        }

        public async Task AdicionarLocalBase(Contrato entity)
        {
        }
    }
```

and here is my test class

```
    [TestClass]
    public class ContratoFactoryTests
    {
        private IContratoPodeSerCriadoValidation _contratoPodeSerCriadoValidation;
        private ContratoFactory _contratoFactory;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void Initialize()
        {
            _contratoPodeSerCriadoValidation = Substitute.For<IContratoPodeSerCriadoValidation>();
            _contratoFactory = new ContratoFactory(_contratoPodeSerCriadoValidation);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public async Task AoSerCriadoOContratoDeveSerValidado()
        {
            var contrato = ContratoValues.ContratoComEmpresaENomeValido;
            await _contratoFactory.Build(contrato);
            _contratoPodeSerCriadoValidation.Valid(contrato).Received();
        }
    }
```

When I run my tests, the thes does not run, or return a "Inconclusive" result.

How can I test Async calls using NSubstitute and FluentAssertions?

UPDATE 19/05/16

I fixed the test methods to return Task instead of void and the tests throws NullReferenceExceptions

Comment: First thing to fix - change your test method to return `Task`, not `void`. That may not be *all* you need to do, but you should certainly do it.

Comment: Thanks =] id Works. And It makes my async tests run. Now, I'm having a NullReferenceObject exception.

Comment: You should update your question with the updated information or delete your question

Comment: I don't see any usage of Fluent Assertions.

Answer (score 2):

I just copy/pasted your code and added a couple of empty interfaces and classes for the missing types. The tests ran just fine out of the box.

As for your question, "How can I test Async calls using NSubstitute and FluentAssertions?", here is how to check for exceptions from an async method.

```
Func<Task> action = async () => await _contratoFactory.Build(contrato);
action.ShouldThrow<SomeValidationFailedException>();
```